# Laravel Eloquent for display row from subject table?

Tags: laravel

i have three database tables

1. category  (id,name)
2. subcategory (id,name,category_id)  foreign_key category_id on table                                                         category(id).
3. subject(id,name,subcategory_id) foreign_key subcategory_id on table subcategory (id).

i want  a row containing the following -

subject_id  subject_name category_name subcategory_id

how to do this using eloquent .and if approach is wrong .please suggest a good method to achieve the same .

Comment: Could you post the code that you have?

Comment: i cant post large codes here
now am using this to display subcategory
$subcategory= Subcategory::with('category')->get();
public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    } .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the following models:

```php
// Category Model
class Category extends \Eloquent {
  protected $table = "category";
  public function subcategory(){
    $this->hasMany('Subcategory','category_id');
  }
}

// Subcategory Model
class Subcategory extends \Eloquent {
  protected $table = "subcategory";
  public function category(){
    $this->belongsTo('Category', 'category_id');
  }
  pubic function subject(){
    $this->hasMany('Subject', 'subcategory_id');
  }
}

// Subject model
class Subject extends \Eloquent {
  protected $table = "subject";
  public function subcategory(){
    $this->belongsTo('Subcategory','subcategory_id');
  }      
}
```

You can get the data in your controller as follows:

```php
// for subject with id 1
public function getOneRow(){
  $subject = Subject::with('subcategory.category')->findOrFail(1);
  //subject_id = $subject->id
  //subject_name = $subject->name
  //subcategory_id = $subject->subcategory->id
  //category_name = $subject->subcategory->category->name
  return array("subject_name"=>$subject->name, "category_name"=>$subject->subcategory->id, "subcategory_name"=>$subject->subcategory->category->name);
}

// for all subjects
public function getOneRow(){
  $subjects = Subject::with('subcategory.category')->all();
  $out = array();
  foreach($subjects as $subject){
  // each row
  //subject_id = $subject->id
  //subject_name = $subject->name
  //subcategory_id = $subject->subcategory->id
  //category_name = $subject->subcategory->category->name
    $out[] = array("subject_name"=>$subject->name, "category_name"=>$subject->subcategory->id, "subcategory_name"=>$subject->subcategory->category->name);
  }
  return $out;
}
```

**Edit for Laravel 5.1**
Your models will be defined differently. Here's an example. Or follow the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent):

```php
// Category Model Laravel 5.1
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Category extends Model {
  protected $table = "category";
  public function subcategory(){
    $this->hasMany('Subcategory','category_id');
  }
}
```

**Edit: Completed the functions with return statements as requested in comment**

Comment: The original was based on Laravel 4.2. I have added a section to show potential changes required in Laravel 5.1

Comment: $subject=Subject::with('subcategoryup.category')->findOrFail(1);

using this am getting this error

ModelNotFoundException in Builder.php line 129:
No query results for model [App\Subject].

Comment: Well, this assumes that you have the Models defined properly and that you have data in your table. `ModelNotFoundException` is thrown because that is what `findOrFail` is supposed to do if it doesn't find an entry in your `subject` table corresponding to `id=1`. If your primary key is not `id`, then you should have `protected $primaryKey = 'subject_id';` in your Model.

Comment: $subjects = Subject::with('subcategory.category')->all();

here instead of ->all(),i just want only few columns from all the tables .can you provide one example .And thanks ,the solution working .But i want to query only few columns .

Comment: It depends on which columns you want. You can specify a filter criteria like so:  `$subject=Subject::with('subcategoryup.category')->where('name','like','maths')->get();` or if you know the ids you want to retrieve: `$subject=Subject::with('subcategoryup.category')->find([1, 3, 5, 7]);`

Comment: i want to fetch only subject name ,category name and subcategory name .
thanks for providing code for filter and specific id ,
but i need to query only columns ...i think we should use something like this ->
$subject=Subject::with('subcategoryup.category')->select('name'.....)..
please improve this

Comment: Checkout the above edits. I have completed the controller methods with return statements like you wanted.

Comment: now i want to edit the subject ,i have used model binding so i can see the previously selected subcategory in subject edit page ,but am unable to select the previously selected category,